# MEF implementation

Tags: c#, mef

I am facing conceptual problem with MEF implementation. Refer below the code I have written.

**Contract Assembly - This is infrastructure code**

```
public interface IHandler<T> 
{
   bool ProcessRequest(T requestObject);
}
```

**AddIn Assembly (Different team will contribute their AddIn)**

```
[Export(typeof(IHandler<MyRequestObject>))]
public class SampleHandler : IHandler<MyRequestObject>
{

   public bool ProcessRequest(MyRequestObject requestObject)
   {
      // My Code
      return false;
   }
}

public class MyRequestObject
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Importer Assembly : Infrastructure code**

```
public class HandlerHelper
{
    [Import(typeof(IHandler<MyRequestObject> ))]
    public IHandler<MyRequestObject> PlugIn { get; set; }


    private CompositionContainer _container;

    public HandlerHelper()
    {
        // Coode to fill the imports of this object

        this._container.ComposeParts(this);
    }

    public bool ExecuteHandler()
    {

        // Dynamically create MyRequestObject and 
        // pass it as parameter to below call            

        //PlugIn.ProcessRequest(varMyRequest);

        return false;
    }
}
```

Inside Importer Assembly I am getting compilation error on

```
[Import(typeof(IHandler<MyRequestObject> ))]
public IHandler<MyRequestObject> PlugIn { get; set; }
```

This assembly can't recognize MyRequestObject as it doesn't exist in current assembly but exist in different Add-In assembly.

also within ExecuteHandler() I want to create object of MyRequestObject  dynamically and again it is invisible since it exist in different assembly

I would appreciate if any one can help me or suggest me an alternative approach

Comment: If the assembly containing `MyRequestObject` is not referenced, it won't be found.  If MyRequestObject is to be shared between both assemblies, then you could put it into a common assembly (like maybe your contract assembly) that both your project and theirs can reference.